# Netbeans "waiting for connection" error only on new project with WAMP

Tags: netbeans, wamp

I'm running NetBeans IDE 8.2 with WAMP 3.1.0 on Windows 10.

On starting a debug session with a new project, the message "Waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)" has recently begun to appear.

Previous projects debug as expected with no change in any configurations. I've created and worked with half a dozen projects on the current setup and none has previously caused trouble.

Could somebody point me to possible reasons why one project can be debugged but another on exactly the same system can't? I've tried everything, even copying over a working project folder and making the necessary changes. (That worked once but not since, unfortunately.)

Comment: Try this setup: [Installing Xdebug for XAMPP with PHP 7.x](https://gist.github.com/odan/1abe76d373a9cbb15bed). The same should apply for WAMP too.

Comment: @DanielO WAMPServer comes with XDEBUG pre-installed

Comment: I should have said in my original question that I had already studied the advice in the previous answers listed above. They provided no help for me because my problem isn't of total failure but a single point of failure on one project out of half a dozen.